# How to add url prefix for server api with traefik?

Tags: microservices, traefik

I'm using `traefik v2` as gateway. I have a frontend container running with host `https://some.site.com` which powered by traefik.

Now I have a micro-service server with multi services and all of them are listening on 80 port. I want to serve the backend server on path `https://some.site.com/api/service1`, `https://some.site.com/api/service2` ...

I have tried `traefik.http.routers.service1.rule=(Host(`some.site.com`) && PathPrefix(`/api/service1`))` but not worked and `traefik.http.middlewares.add-api.addprefix.prefix=/api/service1` not worked too;

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2):

Can you post your services' docker-compose configuration? 
If you use middlewares, you may need to specify the service. Like

```
traefik.http.routers.service1.middlewares=add-api
traefik.http.middlewares.add-api.addprefix.prefix=/api/service1
```

Comment: Yes, it's right. But `traefik.http.routers.service1.rule=Host(`some.site.com`) && PathPrefix(`/service1`)` is also nedded.

Comment: Not working for me in traefik v2.2: `level=error msg="addprefix cannot be a standalone element (type *dynamic.AddPrefix)" providerName=docker`. Until now I was unable to understand what means to be a `standalone element` and how to use the `addprefix`.

Comment: actually I was missing the `.prefix=` in label. but now i got `499 Client Closed Request' caused by: context canceled`